# Return a function with arbitrary properties in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a hook `useEvent` which takes a function and needs to return an event. However, I'm having trouble to match the return type of the hook.

```
const useEvent = (event: (events: Events) => Function) => {
  const { events }: { events: Events } = useContext(Context);
  return useMemo(() => {
      return event(events);
    }
  }, [event, events]);
};
```

And this is how I get the events in the components:

```
const trackClick = useEvent(events => events.trackClickedApp);
...
trackClick(name, page, location, variable);
```

I wanted it to be more specific than `Function`. I created interfaces for all the events which can take input

```
interface trackClickSortBy {
  (sort: string): void;
}
interface trackClickedApp {
  (
    name: string,
    page: string,
    location: string | null,
    variable: string | null,
  ): void;
}
...
```

Then I added all these interfaces to a type `Event`.

```
type Event = trackClickSortBy | trackClickedApp | ...;
```

And finally add the new type to the return of the hook

```
const useEvent = (event: (events: Events) => Event) => {
```

I expected this to work, but it doesn't. In three cases I get `Expected 7 arguments, but got 2`
Any other way that I can solve this? 
Please let me know if there's any info I should provide

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Generics.

This is how it looks in the end:

```
const useEvent = <T>(event: (events: Events) => T)
```